# c# How to validate parameters in VS2017 IDE similar to string.Format

Tags: c#, validation, visual-studio-2017, ide

I noticed that in the VS2017 IDE, a line like the following

```
string.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Has the `{4}` highlighted with a green squiggly underline. When hovering over it, the warning "Format string contains invalid placeholder" is shown, indicating that the IDE for VS2017 is capable of validating the parameters for a call to functions like string.Format.

This is great, because I get immediate feedback about the problem while I'm writing code with a mismatch between the format string and the arguments, rather than some time later at runtime. However, if I define my own functions with similar prototypes to string.Format, and which use string.Format internally, no parameter validation is done.

```
class Example
{
  void ThrowException(string format, params object[] args)
  {
    throw new Exception(string.Format(format, args));
  }

  void LogMessage(int errorCode, string format, params object[] args)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException("No logger!", new Exception(string.Format(format, args)));
  }

  void Main()
  {
    string.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    ThrowException("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    LogMessage(0, "{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", 1, 2, 3, 4);
  }
}
```

[image: Main() function as it appears in IDE]

Only the line with `string.Format` shows the validation error. This means that when calling my custom functions that require the same validation, I only detect the problem as a runtime error.

I looked at [the reference source for string.Format](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,ad9f5b0b214ae8f3), hoping to be able to copy an attribute that configures the IDE validation, but did not see anything relevant there, and couldn't figure out good search terms to find if this has been asked elsewhere (e.g. a [google search for the exact error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Format%20string%20contains%20invalid%20placeholder%22) only seemed to find the Roslyn source that generates the error)

What controls whether the IDE performs validations of this kind on a format string, and how would I enable it for my own code such as the example functions?

Comment: The underlining here is done by static analysis of your code. It's horribly complicated to follow these values into other functions and detect if you have missed values. Also, you may want to allow those missed values - the compiler cannot know your intent.

Comment: If you want to add custom validations to VS, you can write a Roslyn-Analyzer, but that is not easy.

Comment: You are passing string argument to the method. Compiler does know know what you are going to do with that string. Static code analysis is performed for string.format method when you pass the format as a constant string to it. If you pass as string variable with a format string in it, the static code analysis does not happen. So what you are asking is kind of no possible. You can create a visual studio extension or something to implement it your way but there is nothing readily available in Visual Studio.

Comment: `var strFormat = "{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}"; var strValue = string.Format(strFormat, 1,2,3,4);` If you change your code to this, you will not see the compiler error or warning.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that's the point - compiler somehow knows my intent when I directly call `string.Format`. I want to tell the compiler that "this `LogMessage` function needs the same validation as `string.Format`". How do I do that?

Comment: As I said, that feature is not readily available. It is only for code written in specific way. You can write your own VS Extension to have this feature.

Comment: @Steve: Well, `string` is a well known class that is an integral part of the Framework so it is understandable that there would be a built-in code analyzer for it. In your case, however, the compiler does not know it needs to apply that type of analysis to your method. This issue is somewhat moot anyways with string interpolation being available.

Answer (score 1):

[Placeholder answer until someone else gives an answer that's likely to be better than this one for later visitors with similar questions!]

To summarise what I understand from the answers given in comments:

This is not possible in Visual Studio 2017 in any reasonably-obvious way.

It requires writing your own Roslyn-Analyzer (as suggested by Flat Eric), or Visual Studio Extension (as suggested by Chetan Ranpariya), and there is no way to simply instruct the compiler to use the existing analyser that is already written for string.Format.

We are instead expected either to redo the same work that Microsoft already did for string.Format, for every function that has similar sets of parameters, or to make do without the same level of assistance in the IDE. (I'm unclear on exactly how much of Microsoft's work needs to be repeated, and it's not a solution I intent to pursue in order to find out).

JuanR also suggests refactoring the code at the calling site to use string interpolation instead (something I just learned about when reading that comment, and probably worth trying).

I'd hoped that DRY principles would be followed in the design of this feature, so that I could just instruct the compiler to apply the well-known code analyser to the 'format' and 'args' parameters of my functions using the same rules as the equivalent parameters for string.Format, but this appears to something that has not yet been designed into the system.